# how to find common words between two vectors of std::string

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I am trying to find common words between 2 vectors of std::string. I want to get those into a sorted list which is sorted by length, and then words of each length to be sorted alphabetically. I need to use stl functions and functors.

My thoughts: 
using a for_each go through first vector and for each word, compare it to the other vector using a functor (if common, append to a list in functor). Then the resulting list will have only common words in it. Here is where I am stuck, I know how to sort alphabetically, but how do I sort them by length and then sort the same length chunks alphabetically? I have looked around stl, but I am not finding what I need. Or, I am just thinking about this the wrong way. Any ideas?

Example:

**vec1:** "and", "thus", "it", "has", "a", "beginning", "and", "end"

**vec2:** "and," "therefore", "stars", "are", "beginning", "to","fall","to","their", "end"

**result:**  "and", "end", "beginning"

Comment: Can you sort the vectors first?

Comment: Yes, if I create a copy of each

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to mention that I can't have duplicates of words in the resulting vector

Answer (score 5):

If you are allowed to sort `vec1` and `vec2`, you can use [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) to sort the vectors according to the criteria you specify and obtain the common elements, ordered by the same criteria:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), funny_comp);
std::sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), funny_comp);
std::list<std::string> intersection;

std::set_intersection(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(),
                      vec2.begin(), vec2.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(intersection),
                      funny_comp);
```

where `funny_comp` compares by string length, and performs a lexicographical comparison of strings if these have the same length:

```
bool funny_comp(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs)
{ 
   return (lhs.size()) == rhs.size()) ? lhs < rhs
                                      : lhs.size() < rhs.size();
}
```

See [working demo here](http://ideone.com/cvXpKq).

Comment: is there a way to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @MarinaGolubtsova Unless I misunderstand you, this solution removes duplicates. See the demo.

Answer (score 1):

If the vectors are sorted you can use std::set_intersection() to find the words common to each.  std::set_intersection() is O(N) time on the number of items.  Sort of course, is O(N log N).

Comment: No vectors aren't sorted, yet O(NlogN) complexity is still better than what I had

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is O(n^2). This means if the length of the vectors is n, you're doing n*n operations: going over one vector, and for each element, going over the other vector to look for it.

If you can sort the vectors (using the `sort` function. No need for fancy sort like you mentioned), the time is O(n). using `set_intersection`. Even if you can't sort them - copy them into new vectors and sort those new vectors. It's sill much faster than what you're proposing.

Comment: You said if you can sort, the time is O(n), Isn't sort O(n log n)?

Answer (score 1):

To sort  by length, then lexically, you need to define a comparison function (or functor) to do that:

```
struct by_len_lex { 
   bool operator()(std::string const &a, std::string const &b) { 
       if (a.length() < b.length())
           return true;
       if (a.length() > b.length())
           return false;
       return a < b;
    }
};

// ...
std::sort(strings1.begin(), strings1.end(), by_len_lex());
std::sort(strings2.begin(), strings2.end(), by_len_lex());

// find intersection:
std::set_intersection(strings1.begin(), strings1.end(), 
                      strings2.begin(), strings2.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(results),
                      by_len_lex());
```

Note that since you're defining the sort criteria, you need to specify the same criteria both when sorting *and* when doing the intersection.

Comment: This does it, but it creates a bunch of duplicates

Comment: Ok, so I added std::unique to your algorithm, wouldn't it be more complex then?

Comment: @MarinaGolubtsova: If you have duplicates in the original input, this will retain them in the output. If you want to eliminate them, you can use `std::unique` to eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but can use map like following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector <string> v1{"and", "thus", "it", "has", 
                  "a", "beginning", "and", "end"};

vector <string> v2{"and" ,"therefore", "stars", 
                   "are", "beginning", "to","fall","to",
                   "their", "end"};

map <string,int> m;

auto check=[&](const string& x) { return m.find(x) != m.end() ; } ;

for_each(v1.begin(),
         v1.end(),
         [&](const string& x){ 
                m[x] =1;
            } 
         );

for_each(v2.begin(),
         v2.end(),
         [&](const string& x){ 
            if(check(x)) 
                cout<<x<<endl;
            } 
         );

}
```